# Sendmail message / header rewrite remove "behalf of"

Tags: linux, postfix, sendmail

How could I remove this in the email message being sent out through `sendmail`?

Is there something that one can do to revise `sendmail.mc`? I read this [reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28797/can-we-remove-on-behalf-of-from-the-from-address-on-messaging-sendemail) already which didn't solve my issue.

```
Name <name@example.com> on behalf of senderalias@example.com
Sent: Wednesday, October 1, 2023 09:11 AM
To: test@example.com
Subject: test
```

to read:

```
senderalias@example.com
Sent: Wednesday, October 1, 2023 09:11 AM
To: test@example.com
Subject: test
```

Per:

> (`-f` flag passed to sendmail) This will create “On behalf of” notices in Microsoft® Outlook, but it may also help track abuse of the mail system since recipients will see the SMTP login used to send each message.

Comment: What MTA are you using? Postfix, the original Sendmail, or something else? Where is the quote at the end taken from and is it related to the MTA you are using?

Comment: Do you want to do it for messages sent by a few OS accounts?